# Ruby on Rails: Passing string array to highchart function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, string, highcharts

I am new to Ruby on Rails and currently working on a graphic with highchart. I need a column chart with categories on the x-axis, where the categories should actually be the users' names (not many users, so that actually does make sense).

Unfortunately, my chart is not showing the string array categories which I define (or retreive from the data) before the chart function is called. Retreiving the names by something as `categories: <%= @users.map { |i| i.name } %>` does not work either.

Here's a minimal example of what I try to do in `show.html.erb`:

```
<% quantities = [1,2,3] %>
<% names = [5,6,7] %>
<% names2 = ['A','B','C'] %>

<div id="container" style="width:60%;height:300px;"></div>
<script>
   $(function () {
      $('#container').highcharts({
         chart: {
            type: 'column'
         },
         xAxis: {
            categories: [ <%= names[0] %>, <%= names[1] %>, "test" ]
         },
         series: [{
            showInLegend: false,
            data: <%= quantities %>
         }]
      });
   });
</script>
```

Using the integer array `names` for the chart is not a problem, but somehow the string array `names2` does not get passed over and the chart is not shown at all when included instead of `names`. Defining the string array inside the function is not a problem either.

Is there any possibility to pass over a string array or retreive this from the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the line of code you use when you pass in names2? It'll help rule syntax errors and stuff like that.

Comment: `categories: [ <%= names2[0] %>, <%= names2[1] %>, "test" ]` for example.        Or I could of course just use `categories: names2` directly, but that doesn't work either

Comment: Sorry, I meant `categories: <%= names2 %>`  :) - just as with the quantities array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you need to translate it from a ruby array to something that your javascript can handle. You may need to cast the array to json, and also mark it as safe. Something like this:

```
<%= escape_javascript names2.to_json %>
```

If `escape_javascript` doesn't work, you can try `raw` as well.

Comment: Perfect!! I already tried `.to_json`, but now with `raw` it finally worked :) Thank you so, so much!!